# Mac chrome not able to add trusted site

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I just switched over from a windows machine to Mac for work and I cant seem to get the configuration for adding my local dev page to by pass the SSL security as the certificate we have for the local has expired.I have this issue for chrome and Safari but for FF I am able to by pass by adding my url to the trusted site list.

Any help is highly appreciated as I'm kind of stuck.

This is what I have tried so far.

1. Disabled the "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" from chrome flags
2. In the keychain, even though my certificate expired I configured it to "Trust Always"

I did try a couple of other setting. But nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty bizarre way to bypass this SSL check, but it worked for me.
Type blindly while in Chrome: "thisisunsafe"

The page will refresh and it will allow you in!